# In Kettle, how to split values of an column and insert into two different tables?

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle

I want to create a Spoon transformation which could split different parts of an column and insert into corresponding tables. 
the source table looks like this

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
 row_id |   Technology
+------------------------------------------------------+
1       | Cobol, programming
2       | Oracle,database
3       | Ruby, programming
4       | Java, programming
5       | Mysql,database
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

One of the target table looks like this, should insert into cobol, Oracle, Ruby and so on

```
+----------------------+
Technologies
+----------------------+
 id   | technology_name
+----------------------+
```

Another target table looks like, should insert into programming and database

```
+----------------------+
 Category
+----------------------+
 id   | category_name
+----------------------+
```

Can anyone please tell me

1. Which type of step to be used to split values of technology column?
2. How to insert value only once?

Comment: Are there always only two values in your comma separated list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "Split Fields" step to split the `Technology` column to two different new columns, `Technologies` and `Category`, and you can trim the resulting string at the same time to remove unwanted spaces:

[image]

You can then `distribute` rows to two different branches:

- on the first branch you can GROUP BY Technologies, and then you can insert the resulting distinct technologies in a table
- on the second branch you can GROUP BY Categories, and then you can insert the resulting distinct categories in another table

The transformation could be similar to this one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can split your 'technology' field with a `Split Fields` step. You'll probably need to pass the result columns through a `String Operations` step to trim it.

You can insert only once with the `Insert/Update` step.